# Array pointer error?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function that takes two parameters;

1. N is the number of positions or array size
2. nr_vals the range of numbers that i get the permutations from; if nr_vals is 3, then it print would permutations of 0~3.

the outer function just prints the base case {0 0 0 0} and then the inner function ( `extra_helper` ) does the rest recursively.

I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on line `temp[N] = i` . Is there an error with the array pointers?

My Code;

outer function; with parameters 3, 2.

```
void perm_rec_1(int N, int nr_vals){
    int array[N];
    for(int i = 0; i<=nr_vals;i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <=nr_vals; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    extra_help(N, nr_vals, array[N]);
}
```

inner function;

```
void extra_help(int N, int nr_vals, int array[])
{
    if (N < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    int temp[N];
    for (int i = 0; i<=nr_vals; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = &array[i];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= nr_vals;i++)
    {
        temp[N] = i;
        for (int z = 0; z <=nr_vals; z++)
        {
            printf("%d",temp[z]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        while(temp[N+1] != NULL)
        {
            int M = N+1;
            for(int innerCounter = 1; innerCounter<=nr_vals; innerCounter++)
            {
                temp[M] = innerCounter;
                for (int z = 0; z <=nr_vals; z++)
                {
                    printf("%d",temp[z]);
                }
            }
            temp[M] = 0;
        }
    }
    extra_help(N-1, nr_vals, &array[N]);
}
```

Comment: `int array[N];` should be `array = malloc(sizeof(int)*N)`

Comment: Same for `int temp[N]`, but in `while(temp[N+1] != NULL)`  i don't get what was suppose to do, N never changes, M inside while never changes, and `temp[M] = 0` is the condition of while because `M = N+1`

Answer (score 0):

your program has many problems:

1. `int array[N];`, use `N` to declare which is not const to declare array, that is not recommended, you can declare like this `const int N=10; int array[N];` or `int *array = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int))`
2. when pass array to function, it actually pass the address of the array, and your `array[N]` is local variable, when you pass it to `extra_help`, the memory of `array[N]` has gone, it actually passed a invalid address
3. when declare `temp[N]`, the temp has N elements indexed from 0 to N-1,
   you can not use temp[N] because the N index is not exist, although the compiler will not always generate an warning or error.

Comment: Regarding your point 1, there's no particular problem with using a non-`const` array size. It's a VLA (variable length array), and it's length is the value of `N` when the array declaration is reached. VLAs do not exist in C90, are supported in C99, and are optional in C11.